# Por que a instância do smtplib não retorna um dicionário?

Tags: python

Estou começando meus estudos em Python e estou com uma dúvida.
Durante a leitura do ebook [Automate the boring stuff](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/) me deparo com uma instância que retorna um determinado objeto.

```
import smtplib
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.example.com', 587)
type(smtpObj)
```

## Retornará:

```
<class 'smtplib.SMTP'>
```

Aí que surge a minha dúvida.
Por que a função `type()`, não retorna?

```
<class 'dict'>
```

Vim do JavaScript, e não sei se existe uma diferença entre objeto e dicionário.

Comment: Sim, existe diferença. Um dicionário é apenas um tipo de objeto. Neste caso, a biblioteca `smtplib` implementa a classe `SMTP` e você está definindo uma instância dela, tal como acontece com as classes do JS.

Comment: Não tô achando nenhum material que detalhe isso. Agradeço o esclarecimento.

Comment: Já verificou a [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) do pacote?

Comment: Em Python um "dicionário" não é a mesma coisa que um "objeto" - são coisas bem diferentes - talvez a maior diferença do Python para o javascript. Recomendo fazer o tutorial oficial da linguagem, passo a passo, em https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Biblioteca `smtplib` (cliente de protocolo `SMTP`)

> O módulo `smtplib` define um objeto de sessão do cliente `SMTP` que pode ser usado para enviar mensagens para qualquer máquina da Internet com um ouvinte daemon `SMTP` ou `ESMTP`. Para obter detalhes sobre a operação `SMTP` e `ESMTP`, consulte [RFC 821 (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821.html) e [RFC 1869 (extensões de serviço `SMTP`)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1869.html).

```
class smtplib.SMTP(host='', port=0, local_hostname=None, [timeout, ]source_address=None)
```

Dicionário em `python`

> Dicionário é um tipo diferente de coleção. Ele é um tipo de mapeamento nativo do `Python`. Um mapa é uma coleção associativa desordenada. A associação, ou mapeamento, é feita a partir de uma chave, que pode ser qualquer tipo imutável, para um valor, que pode ser qualquer objeto de dados do `Python`.

Logo, sabendo-se disto podemos ver claramente que existe diferença entre um dicionário e a biblioteca `smtplib`... A biblioteca `smtplib` implementa apenas a `class SMTP` (onde você instância a mesma) e um dicionário é apenas um tipo de objeto, por isto acontece o que você disse na sua pergunta sobre o `type(smtpObj)`.

**NOTA**

> Neste [exemplo do Alura](https://blog.alura.com.br/trabalhando-com-o-dicionario-no-python/) você pode ver claramente o funcionamento de um dicionário.